# Find the minimum of a 2d interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to find the minimum of a 2d interpolation. I"m really stuck on trying to find a way to appropriately pass the data to the optimizer,

here is the code I have so far:

```
import scipy
from scipy.interpolate import interp2d
a_ca_energy_interp = interp2d(a, c_a, Energy)

def run_2d_params(params, func):
    a, b = params
    return func(a, b)

scipy.optimize.fmin(run_2d_params, np.array([1.60,6.075]),
                    args=a_ca_energy_interp)
```

Which throws the error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "interp2d") to tuple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`args` must be a tuple, even if it is only one argument:

```
scipy.optimize.fmin(run_2d_params, np.array([1.60,6.075]),
                    args=(a_ca_energy_interp, ))
```